# PHP's SimpleXML doesn't keep order between different element types

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

As far as I can tell, when you have multiple types of elements at the same level in an XML document tree, PHP's `SimpleXML`, including `SimpleXMLElement` and `SimpleXMLIterator` both don't keep the order of the elements as they relate to each other, only within each element.

For example, consider the following structure:

```
<catalog>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</title>
        <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Great Expectations</title>
        <author>Charles Dickens</author>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

If I had this structure and used either `SimpleXMLIterator` or `SimpleXMLElement` to parse it, I would end up with an array that looked something like this:

```
Array (
    [book] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
            )
            [author] => Array (
                [0] => J.K. Rowling
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => Great Expectations
            )
            [author] => Array (
                [0] => Charles Dickens
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This would be fine, since I only have book elements, and it keeps the order properly within those elements. However, say I add movie elements, too:

```
<catalog>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</title>
        <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <movie>
        <title>The Dark Knight</title>
        <director>Christopher Nolan</director>
    </movie>
    <book>
        <title>Great Expectations</title>
        <author>Charles Dickens</author>
    </book>
    <movie>
        <title>Avatar</title>
        <director>Christopher Nolan</director>
    </movie>
</catalog>
```

Parsing with `SimpleXMLIterator` or `SimpleXMLElement` would result in the following array:

```
Array (
    [book] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
            )
            [author] => Array (
                [0] => J.K. Rowling
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => Great Expectations
            )
            [author] => Array (
                [0] => Charles Dickens
            )
        )
    )
    [movie] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => The Dark Knight
            )
            [director] => Array (
                [0] => Christopher Nolan
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [title] => Array (
                [0] => Avatar
            )
            [director] => Array (
                [0] => James Cameron
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Because it represents the data this way, it seems that I have no way to tell that the order of the books and movies in the XML file was actually `book, movie, book, movie`. It just separates them into two categories (although it keeps the order within each category).

Does anyone know of a workaround, or a different XML parser that doesn't have this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"If I ... used either SimpleXMLIterator or SimpleXMLElement to parse it, I would end up with an array" - no you wouldn't, you would end up with an object, which happens to behave like an array in certain ways.

The output of a recursive dump of that object *is not* the same as the result of iterating over it.

In particular, running `foreach( $some_node->children() as $child_node )` will give you all the children of a node in the order they appear in the document, regardless of name, as shown in [this live code demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SoWKoA).

Code:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<catalog>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</title>
        <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <movie>
        <title>The Dark Knight</title>
        <director>Christopher Nolan</director>
    </movie>
    <book>
        <title>Great Expectations</title>
        <author>Charles Dickens</author>
    </book>
    <movie>
        <title>Avatar</title>
        <director>Christopher Nolan</director>
    </movie>
</catalog>
EOF;

$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ( $sx->children() as $node )
{
    echo $node->getName(), '<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
book
movie
book
movie
```

Comment: Hm, okay, thanks! I know that you get an object, but when I parsed with `SimpleXMLIterator`, in my case, I *did* end up with an array, because as I parsed I put all of the stuff into an array. But I must have done something wrong, because your code is not only extremely straightforward but works like I want it to. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshSherick The array structure you created had no way of preserving the order of items, because there were only two top-level items in your result: `'book'` and `'movie'`. It's a good example of why having a SimpleXML object is better than trying to represent an entire XML document as an array - different purposes call for different kinds of traversal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Order annotation:

```
@Root(name="Person")
@Order(elements={"first", "second", "third"})
public class Person {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;
}
```

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize

Comment: You appear to have misread the question. This is about the PHP module called SimpleXML, nothing to do with the Java library with a similar name.